# MySQL Select From To And Show Results Without Marker

Tags: mysql, variables, filter

I have table:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | channel           |
+----+-------------------+
| m2 | AA-AA             |
| 1  | KR_A 1            |
| 2  | KR_A 2            |
| 11 | HR_A 3            |
| 12 | HR_B 1            |
| m4 | BB-BB             |
| m3 | CC-CC             |
| 17 | SR_B 1            |
| m5 | DD-DD             |
| m1 | EE-EE             |
+----+-------------------+
```

When i add `m2` query needs to return:

```
1
2
11
12
```

So i use this query:

```
SET @showChannels:=0;
SELECT id, channel
FROM table
WHERE
(
   @showChannels:=( (id like 'm%' and id = 'm2' and @showChannels) or (id not like 'm%' ) )
)
AND id not like 'm%';
```

That returns correctly above desired results.

Problem is this when i add `m3` to query i need to get this:

```
17
```

BUT i get always:

```
1
2
11
12
```

And that is not correct because i need to get only 17 value...could be any help to modify it to work? I try today for 4 hours and was unable to achieve the desired result.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "add m3 to the query"?

Comment: It also seems like you may be relying on your records being in a specific order. Unless you have a column with a reliable sequence that you can use for sorting, you can never guarantee that when you select records from a table that they will be returned in a specific order.

Comment: Order is like this...markers begins with 'm%' and others are numbers (integer type) so could you try to make query using above table please? I need to finish project

Comment: What I mean is, no matter how you select, or order (given your above table structure and data) you can never guarantee that your result set will return in the order you wish. That means that if you are relying on a marker occurring before or after a set of records to flag those records as wanted, your data could potentially be incorrect. If you are determined to go this route, I would suggest adding a new `NUMBER` type column to the table: `seq`, that you can fill with a value you would use to sort your result set. That way you could, more reliably, continue in the direction you are going.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer...could you please give me as answer simple code for seq and NUMBER column example so that i then can implement on query and finish project...please if you have time to replay

Comment: Sure, I could add an answer that can get you going in the correct direction, but given what you have available, and what you are asking for, it may require some extra work on your end to fully implement it. Give a bit to write it up and I will post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimal changes, you can add a sort column to your table, and update the values to the values you want that reflects the proper sorting:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN sort_seq INTEGER;

UPDATE table SET sort_seq = 1 WHERE id = 'm2';
UPDATE table SET sort_seq = 2 WHERE id = '1';
UPDATE table SET sort_seq = 3 WHERE id = '2';
UPDATE table SET sort_seq = 4 WHERE id = '11';
UPDATE table SET sort_seq = 5 WHERE id = '12';
UPDATE table SET sort_seq = 6 WHERE id = 'm4';
UPDATE table SET sort_seq = 7 WHERE id = 'm3';
UPDATE table SET sort_seq = 8 WHERE id = '17';
UPDATE table SET sort_seq = 9 WHERE id = 'm5';
UPDATE table SET sort_seq = 10 WHERE id = 'm1';
```

However, the core problem that you are having is that you need to back-reference to a "marker" of some kind. The better way to do that would have been to have a way to group your records. You can do that by adding a lookup table for groups for your records:

```
+----+-------------------+--------+--------+
| id | channel           |  grp   |  sort  |
+----+-------------------+--------+--------+
| m2 | AA-AA             |   m2   |    1   |
| 1  | KR_A 1            |   m2   |    2   |
| 2  | KR_A 2            |   m2   |    3   |
| 11 | HR_A 3            |   m2   |    4   |
| 12 | HR_B 1            |   m2   |    5   |
| m4 | BB-BB             |   m4   |    6   |
| m3 | CC-CC             |   m3   |    7   |
| 17 | SR_B 1            |   m3   |    8   |
| m5 | DD-DD             |   m5   |    9   |
| m1 | EE-EE             |   m1   |   10   |
+----+-------------------+--------+--------+

+----+--------------------+--------+
| id | group_desc         |  sort  |
+----+--------------------+--------+
| m1 | Description for m1 |   1    |
| m2 | Description for m2 |   2    |
| m3 | Description for m3 |   3    |
| m4 | Description for m4 |   4    |
| m5 | Description for m5 |   5    |
+----+--------------------+--------+
```

Then you could `JOIN` on that table to select only items belonging to your group and/or sort on that group.

```
SELECT c.id, c.channel
FROM channels c
JOIN channel_groups cg
ON cg.id = c.grp
AND c.id <> cg.id
WHERE cg.id = 'm2'
ORDER BY c.sort;
```

Or you can use a similar query, but you can identify the group channel as the primary using a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT c.id, c.channel, CASE WHEN c.id = cg.id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS primary
FROM channels c
JOIN channel_group cg
ON cg.id = c.grp
ORDER BY c.sort;
```

Comment: Thanks i will implement your idea to my project..i have now starting points so thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
+----+-------------------+--------+
| id | channel           |  seq   |
+----+-------------------+--------+
| m2 | AA-AA             |   m2   |
| 1  | KR_A 1            |   1    |
| 2  | KR_A 2            |   2    |
| 11 | HR_A 3            |  11    |
| 12 | HR_B 1            |  12    |
| m4 | BB-BB             |  m4    |
| m3 | CC-CC             |  m3    |
| 17 | SR_B 1            |  17    |
| m5 | DD-DD             |  m5    |
| m1 | EE-EE             |  m1    |
+----+-------------------+--------+
```

I added `seq` tableas sugessted by gmiley but not sure if it can hold m% markers because it is `NUMBER` type column `seq` so i im not sure if i done it right.

Another query what i im thinking is why can't i use for example `BETWEEN` like this:

```
SELECT id, channel
FROM table
WHERE id BETWEEN 'm2' AND 'm%'
AND id NOT LIKE 'm%';
```

This way it will be more simple because it will select from m2 to next m marker value

More important is that sort column have this order:

```
["m2","1","2","11","12","m4","m3","17", "m5","m1"]
```

in MySQL database so it's type is TEXT, maybe this will be simple to omplement from to...