# MySQL IF THEN not working using multiple IF THEN ELSEIF

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SET @foundMarker:=0;
SELECT id, channel
FROM myTable
WHERE (
   IF (id like 'm%' AND id = 'm2') THEN SET @foundMarker=1;
       ELSEIF (id like 'm%' and @foundMarker=1) THEN SET @foundMarker=0;
       END IF;
   )
ORDER BY LOCATE(CONCAT('"', id, '"'), sort);
```

So what i need to acomplish here is to check if i found 'm2' marker set the foundMarker flag to 1 and read next row....check again and if i found one marker with that begins with 'm' (for example 'm4') set the foundMarker flag to 0.

So this way i show from marker to marker values (other values are the integer types).

So i got stuck with error:

```
IF (id like 'm%' AND id = 'm2') THEN SET @foundMarker=1;
ELSEIF (id like 'm%' and @foundMarker=1) THEN SET @foundMarker=0;
ELSEIF (@foundMarker=1) THEN @showChannels:=(id not like 'm%' and @showChannels)
END IF;
```

How to write it correctly so that query will run and set user defined variables? I read MySQL manual page but this above code won't run query...i got error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') THEN SET @foundMarker=1' at line 29

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSEIF (id like 'm%' and @foundMarker=1) THEN SET @foundMarker=0' at line 1

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 1
```

If above IF can be written using simple and faster query please let me know.

Comment: You would be better off providing a sample of your input data (the original data from the table you are selecting from) and the desired output results of your query. As is, what you are trying to do makes little sense. You do not use `IF` statements within queries like that. At most you would want a `CASE` statement, but upon inspection of your query, it seems you are trying to do some sort of aggregate select. I would really recommend reading  [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing the sample input/output.

Comment: You are right...sorry for that...i have posted question with sample table and query try but none replay so if you could take a look....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56418608/mysql-select-from-to-and-show-results-without-marker

Comment: As you can see i need to query from to....but i always get same result from first marker....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Select From To And Show Results Without Marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56418608/mysql-select-from-to-and-show-results-without-marker)

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu it is a duplicate (and from the same person), however that question was never answered. So, until it is, I would not link this question to that one.